# How to three.js using Two dimensional one or two shape diagram merge draw?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, geometry

I am new in three js. I attempt to one shape diagram into another shape add/group. ('I Drawn in one square object and I Drawn in another one square object. This two object How to merge double line square object display'). i tried to different method. Below my code.

```
//method 1

function doubleSquareDraw(startX, startY, endX, endY, color){

   var square = new THREE.Shape();
   square.moveTo(startX, startY, 0);
   square.lineTo(endX, startY, 0);
   square.lineTo(endX, endY, 0);
   square.lineTo(startX, endY, 0);
   square.lineTo(startX, startY, 0);

   var square2 = new THREE.Path();
   square2.moveTo(startX + 4 , startY  - 4 , 0);
   square2.lineTo(endX - 4 , startY - 4 , 0);
   square2.lineTo(endX - 4, endY + 4 , 0);
   square2.lineTo(startX + 4 , endY + 4 , 0);
   square2.lineTo(startX + 4 , startY  - 4 , 0);
   square.holes.push( square2);

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(square.getPoints());  
  var doubleLineSquare = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: color
    }));

    return doubleLineSquare;
}

//method 2

 var bed = new THREE.Shape();
         bed.moveTo(startX, startY, 0);
         bed.lineTo(endX, startY, 0);
         bed.lineTo(endX, endY, 0);
         bed.lineTo(startX, endY, 0);
         bed.lineTo(startX, startY, 0);

          var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(bed.getPoints());
        var bed = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: "#000000"
        }));

         var bed2 = new THREE.Path();
         bed2.moveTo(startX + 10, startY - 10, 0);
         bed2.lineTo(endX - 10, startY - 10, 0);
         bed2.lineTo(endX - 10, endY + 10, 0);
         bed2.lineTo(startX + 10, endY + 10, 0);
         bed2.lineTo(startX + 10, startY - 10, 0);

          var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(bed2.getPoints());
          var bed = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: "#000000"
          }));

           var group = new THREE.Group();
           group.add( bed );
           group.add( bed2 );
           return group;
}
```

Comment: Try it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6200/

Comment: Thank you so much. it's wok. @Mugen87